# Placeholder for body off in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The placeholder for the body field (the word "Body") is strangely placed in the Android app, seems a bit too high:

[image: screenshot]

**Could reproduce using**:

- Samsung Galaxy 4a.  Android version 4.4.2  App version 1.0.54
- Moto X (2013), Android 4.4.4 App version 1.0.60

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my stock Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 using v1.0.55 (beta) of the app. Is it possible to add a little detail like what device you're using, what version of Android and what version of the app?

Comment: @StevenV sure Samsung Galaxy 4a.  Android version 4.4.2  App version 1.0.54

Comment: Repro on XPERIA M 1.0.57

Comment: @JonH may I add that to the question?

Comment: Repro on Moto X (2013), Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 2):

This alignment issue was fixed in the Stack Exchange Android App `1.0.89` and the higher versions.

Also I have verified in the recent version `1.0.92` too.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: SE Android app alignment issue was solved]