# Text is overflowing form fields in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When writing posts in the Android app, some of text is getting outside the lines. This is only in the main body, not in the title or tags fields

[image: entering a question]

As you can see, it happens when posting answers, too.

[image: entering an answer]

Motorola Moto X (1st gen) with Android 4.4.4.

(This may be related to [Placeholder for body off in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247776/watermark-for-body-off-in-android-app))

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing does not happen on my Nexus 7 (2012) with Android 5.1.