# Text overflows and formatting bar disappears after adding image

Tags: bug, android-app, uploader

After uploading an image the formatting bar disappears as below

[image]

To get it back you have to delete the extra line after the image

[image]

Also the text on the question text area is overflowing. I'm using a Moto G 2013 on Android 4.4.4.

Comment: The overflowing text area is [a known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247776/placeholder-for-body-off-in-android-app). As for the formatting toolbar, AFAIK you have to start writing to make it appear.